# Series to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

I have the following code and output

```
    mean = dataframe.groupby('LABEL')['RESP'].mean()
    minimum = dataframe.groupby('LABEL')['RESP'].min()
    maximum = dataframe.groupby('LABEL')['RESP'].max()
    std = dataframe.groupby('LABEL')['RESP'].std()
    df = [mean, minimum, maximum]
```

And the following output

```
[LABEL
     0.0   -1.193420
     1.0    0.713425
     2.0   -1.066513
     3.0   -0.530640
     4.0   -2.130600
     6.0    0.084747
     7.0    1.190506
     Name: RESP, dtype: float64,
     LABEL
     0.0   -1.396179
     1.0   -0.233459
     2.0   -1.631165
     3.0   -1.271057
     4.0   -2.543640
     6.0   -0.418091
     7.0   -0.004578
     Name: RESP, dtype: float64,
     LABEL
     0.0    0.042247
     1.0    0.295534
     2.0    0.128233
     3.0    0.243975
     4.0    0.088077
     6.0    0.085615
     7.0    0.693196
     Name: RESP, dtype: float64

]
```

However I want the output to be a dictionary as

```
{label_value: [mean, min, max, std_dev]}
```

For example

```
{1: [1, 0, 2, 1], 2: [0, -1, 1, 1], ... }
```

Comment: Read about the `.agg()` method, you will need it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your starting Dataframe is equivalent to one I've synthesised.

1. calculate all of the aggregate values in one call to aggregate. rounded values so output fits in this answer
2. `reset_index()` on aggregate then `to_dict()`
3. list comprehension to reformat `dict` to your specification

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[l, random.random()] for l in range(8) for k in range(500)], columns=["LABEL","RESP"])
d = df.groupby("LABEL")["RESP"].agg([np.mean, np.min, np.max, np.std]).round(4).reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
{e["LABEL"]:[e["mean"],e["amin"],e["amax"],e["std"]] for e in d}
```

**output**

```
{0: [0.5007, 0.0029, 0.997, 0.2842],
 1: [0.4967, 0.0001, 0.9993, 0.2855],
 2: [0.4742, 0.0003, 0.9931, 0.2799],
 3: [0.5175, 0.0062, 0.9996, 0.2978],
 4: [0.4909, 0.0018, 0.9952, 0.2912],
 5: [0.4787, 0.0077, 0.9976, 0.291],
 6: [0.4878, 0.0009, 0.9942, 0.2806],
 7: [0.4989, 0.0066, 0.9982, 0.278]}
```